# How do you set a value from a getter?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

How do I set the geocode from the response.loc:  **`$("#details").html("Location: " + response.loc);`**.

As the value for: **`var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.6162,16.5528);`**

```
var geocoder;
var map;
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
var marker;
function initialize() {
  geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(59.6162,16.5528);
  var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: latlng,
    mapTypeId: 'hybrid'
  }
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);
}

function codeLatLng() {
  var input = document.getElementById('latlng').value;
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', 2);
  var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(15);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map

        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// get geocode from IP //

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("Your IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html("Location: " + response.loc);
}, "jsonp");
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass response.loc as parameter to the function codeLatLng.

```
function codeLatLng(loc) {
  var latlngStr = input.split(',', loc);
  var lat = parseFloat(latlngStr[0]);
  var lng = parseFloat(latlngStr[1]);
  var latlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
  geocoder.geocode({'latLng': latlng}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
      if (results[1]) {
        map.setZoom(15);
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: latlng,
            map: map

        });
        infowindow.setContent(results[1].formatted_address);
        infowindow.open(map, marker);
      } else {
        alert('No results found');
      }
    } else {
      alert('Geocoder failed due to: ' + status);
    }
  });
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);

// get geocode from IP //

$.get("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
    $("#ip").html("Your IP: " + response.ip);
    $("#address").html("Location: " + response.city + ", " + response.region);
    $("#details").html("Location: " + response.loc);
    codeLatLng(response.loc);
}, "jsonp");
```